# Insert New Row Without Inheriting Lock Properties

Tags: vba, excel

Here's the Deal:

I have a Protected Worksheet with a locked dynamic Range (for the purpose of understanding let's say: A1:E100). I have allow in the protection properties to insert and delete new rows. So, if I want to insert a row between A10 and A11 it will let me. However, if I want to add content to this row it will not let me because it inherited the properties from the Cells Above.

If I inserted a new row in cell A250 I won'r have a problem of course, because this part of the sheet is not locked. Obviously I want to insert the Row between the mentioned dynamic define range (A1:E100).

Is there a way to insert new rows without inheriting the properties from the cell Above? 
Is there a way that the new inserted rows aren't locked?

I want to keep my locked Range as it is right now and I don't to insert the row if some other Range that is not between my defined Range.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Comment: Copy an unlocked row and *insert copied cells* where you want them?

Comment: Thanks, but this not my optimal solution. I don't want users to mess with this. Any other idea...?

Comment: Unlock, carry out the operation, lock again. It's quite normal to do that.

Comment: My end users don't have access to unlock. Think of it as a big application that more than 200 people use. The range is locked so they can't modify the content but they should be able to add a new row where they can insert data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could unprotect and protect the sheet yourself when a new row is added. You might want use better checks if the target is a newly added row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Locked = False Then Exit Sub 'only execute if target is locked (which means the only way it could have changed is if it was inserted, I hope)
    Me.Unprotect
    Target.EntireRow.Locked = False
    Me.Protect AllowInsertingRows:=True
End Sub
```

You also might want to check if the sheet was protected or not using `Sheet.ProtectContents`. Otherwise it will unlock stuff if you unprotect it manually and change something within in the locked rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer, I think this is a great solution actually. I didn't want to use Events but I guess is my only shot. I was hoping that modifying some Excel properties it would let me do it.